# How to prove easily that geodesic is auto parallel?

Tags: differential-geometry

I only have the elementary concept of geodesic and differential equn of geodesic. Intrinsic derivative =0 implies parallel displacement along a curve. What does it mean by auto parallel? How to prove easily that geodesic is auto parallel ?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

$\frac{d^2x^a}{ds^2} + \Gamma^{a}_{bc}\frac{dx^b}{ds}\frac{dx^c}{ds} = 0$
This is the required differential equations of geodesic.
Which reduces to
 \frac{dx^a}_{;b} \frac{dx^b} =0
This shows that the unit tangent vector \frac{dx^a} suffers a parallel displacement along the geodesic curve. 
Hence proved.

Comment: What is this i dont understand what have you written

Comment: Oh you are taking intrinsic derivative. Thank you so much